# What is wrong with my 1997 Honda CBR 600 F3? No signs of life

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, fuse

So obviously in the title I have a 1997 Honda CBR 600 F3. As of right now it is showing no signs of life. I just replaced the battery and tested it right before I wrote this. It reads 12.75 volts. Everything appeared to be hooked up properly on the bike. (Other than the voltage regulator). When I turn the key to the on position no lights come on or anything. I have checked the fuse box as well as the fuses next to the battery they are all tested and functional. Additionally, I was testing the voltage on the left and right side of the starter relay and the left side has no voltage coming out of it. I attempted to jump start the bike hooked up to a car and the bike showed no signs of life. Please help!

Comment: Is there power coming out of your Ignition switch

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a poor connection (battery terminals), a broken wire or a loose connection that was disturbed when you replaced the battery.

1) Clean and check the battery terminals,

2) then gently agitate the wires to see if things come on - if they do then find the loose one - it will be a main (large) wire.

Note, finding electrical faults can be likened to finding the needle in a haystack... And when you find it and tell someone they say “oh that was simple then” - usually the foreman who thinks you were doing something else...

Answer (score 1):

Check carefully the ramp of electrical connectors behind the dashboard (three 8mm hex screws to remove)
There is one which totally kills the bike's elec if it is unplugged, and it happened twice on my F3, because the plastic clip of the connector was not holding it in place and it came loose.

It is on the left on the ramp, a white one with 2 or 3 pins, if I remember correctly. It is probably the connector that links the key contactor to the whole harness.

Be careful when removing the dashboard to not pull too hard on its connectors, there is not much excess length and it is not super easy to fit it in or out of its space between the handlebars and the windscreen. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You might have your starter solenoid installed backwards like I did had the same problem